# What're the differences between pointwise convergence and coordinatewise convergence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

This is a pretty basic question. I cannot tell the similarities and differences between pointwise convergence and coordinatewise convergence. Even I do not know the definitions of both. Can you show me some examples about them?

Comment: I have never heard of *coordinate convergence*. What's the context?

Comment: @user127001: oops!that should be coordinatewise convergence. Sorry.

Comment: Even so. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If coordinate wise convergence means that each coordinates converges, then the only place they could be different is in a space with infinitely many coordinates.

For instance, in the space of the countable product of the reals with the box topology, the sequence of sequences (0,1,1,1,...), (0,0,1,1,...) converges coordinatewise to 0 but not pointwise. I can provide more details on request.

Comment: What is "box topology"?

Comment: What do you mean by “pointwise”?  As I understand that term, it means exactly what you’re meaning by coordinatewise, and I would say that the sequences of sequences you give does converge pointwise to (0,0,…).

Comment: With infinite coordinates, there are many choices of what constitutes convergence, called topologies. Pointwise convergence is coordinatewise convergence only in the product topology, which is the most common.